# Find $\bigcup A_n$ and $\bigcap A_n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n=\left (-\dfrac{1}{k},1\right ]\cup \left ( 2, \dfrac{3k-1}{k}\right ]$, for $n\in\Bbb N$.

What I found was that $ \bigcup A_n = (-1,1] \cup (2,3) $ and $ \bigcap A_n = (0,1] $, are they ok?

Comment: Note that 0 belongs to all of the sets. Other than that, your answer seems correct.

Comment: Thanks, sir. @VasiliiIugov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection:
$\cap A_n=[0,1]\cup (2, 2.5]$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $ -1 $ and $ 0 $ enter both sets, if they are open intervals on the left? And thanks :).

Comment: Now that I realize it, wouldn't the intersection give $ [0,1] \cup (2,5 / 2) $?